# MYSQL, Include Null Results

Tags: mysql

Want a null row where no data exist

Hello.  This is in regards to MySQL Workbench 6.3.

I'm trying to return a list of results for every item listed in my select statement, which would include those items that don't actually exist.  So if i list 5 items in my select statement and only 3 exist, i'd like to get 5 rows returned, 3 actual rows with data and 2 more rows that only show null. Can someone please show me how to edit my query below to show this ? Thank you !

```
select emails from table where email in (dog, frog, cat, tiger, lizard);
```

Actual Result (only the 3 emails that actual exist show)

```
dog
cat
tiger
```

Desired Result

```
dog
null
cat
tiger
null
```

Comment: why not `select emails from table`

Comment: The desired results are not possible.. You can't expect MySQL to return the selected records in the order they went in the `IN()` operator.

Answer (score 1):

> The desired results are not possible.. You can't expect MySQL to
>   return the selected records in the order they went in the IN()
>   operator.

So i think you better off when you change the desired result to something you know sometiming was not found in the table, i think you are looking for.

**Query**

```
 SELECT 
    search_emails.email 
  , (
      CASE
         WHEN t.email IS NOT NULL
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' 
      END
    ) AS found
FROM (
  SELECT 'dog' AS email
  UNION
  SELECT 'frog' AS email
  UNION 
  SELECT 'cat' AS email
  UNION 
  SELECT 'tiger' AS email
  UNION 
  SELECT 'lizard' AS email
) AS search_emails 
LEFT JOIN 
 t
ON
 t.email = search_emails.email
```

**Result**

```
| email  | found |
| ------ | ----- |
| dog    | true  |
| cat    | true  |
| tiger  | true  |
| frog   | false |
| lizard | false |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zUHbftKgSmfe71HVoKGDi/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select emails from table where email in (dog, frog, cat, tiger, lizard) OR email IS NULL
```

be sure that the values provided for `IN (...)` are provided as strings.

Comment: why? it's valid SQL. yes "table" is a keyword. but I copied that from the question assuming it is a placeholder

Comment: `in (dog, frog, cat, tiger, lizard)` is not valid SQL.. will give  unknown column errors ..

Comment: also copied from the question... assuiming they are placeholders

Comment: "be sure that the values provided for IN (...) are provided as strings" Besides the query [won't](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zUHbftKgSmfe71HVoKGDi/0) generate the non matching results for 'frog' and 'lizard' the added `OR` will not change that.